# Text centered in div with another div on left with right border

Tags: html, css

Sorry but I didn't know how to describe post title.
I would like to achieve something like in screenshot using html/css:

[image: screen]

It's gonna be some kind of title/header for my columns.
I would like ABC be centered vertically and horizontally in blue border. Also red dot (I want to put there small img) should be centered vertically and there should be 1px thick gray line on right side of image.
How to do that?

I've tried something like this but line is too short:

```
<div style="background: #75d0ff;">

  <div style="border-right: 1px solid gray; padding: 20px; display: inline; height: 100%;">
      <img src="css/img/dot.png">
  </div>

  <div class="border-content" style="display: inline">
      <p class="text-center">ABC</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the text centered in the center of the complete result or only in the right blue part?

Comment: @svenb text should be centered in complete result (just like in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be the right way:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #67CDFB;
  width: 200px;
}

#textPusher {
  width: 100%;
  height:35%;
}
#imgContainer{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  border-right:1px solid red;
}

#imgContainer img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <div id="textPusher"></div>
  <div id="textContainer">abc</div>
  <div id="imgContainer"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt=""></div>
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer but text is centered inside "right part div" (right of vertical line) not in whole container. How to fix it? Is it possible to do that without hardcoding height of div?

Comment: @user3626048 I changed the code so that the centering does not depend on the div height (hope this is what you meant with not hard-coding the div height)

Comment: @user3626048 No problem

Answer (score 1):

```css
      #container
      {
        width:200px;
        height:40px;
        background-color:#75d0ff;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:arial;
      }

      #container-circle
      {
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
        position:absolute;
        width: 40px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-right:5px;
        border-right:2px solid orange;
      }

      #circle
      {

        top:15px;

        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border:2px solid red

      }
      #tekst
      {
        padding-top:10px;
        width:200px;
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:bold;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="container-circle">
        <div id="circle">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tekst">
        ABC
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you. Do you know is it possible to do that without hardcoding height of div?

Comment: @user3626048 use % instead of px. Does this answer your question or do you need something else?

Comment: @user3626048 no problem, if one of the answers is what you wanted you can mark it as accepted to close the question.